# Using data from URL Request in Python

Tags: url, request

I am getting data back from a URL request and the response seems to be headers and data in the form of csv.  How do I make this data into something useable inside of Python?

#pulls weather data from visual crossing
#https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather/weather-data-services

```
#pulls weather data from visual crossing
#https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather/weather-data-services

import requests

#create URL
url = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Edmonton?unitGroup=metric&include=current&key=[API CREDENTIALS]&contentType=csv"

#request Instance, returns data as a string ISO-8859-1
html = requests.get(url).text
print(html)
```

The response I get is below....

```
name,datetime,temp,feelslike,dew,humidity,precip,precipprob,preciptype,snow,snowdepth,windgust,windspeed,winddir,sealevelpressure,cloudcover,visibility,solarradiation,solarenergy,uvindex,severerisk,conditions,icon,stations
"Edmonton, AB, Canada",2023-01-07T23:31:02,-9.6,-9.6,-11.4,86.7,0,0,,0,0,,7.9,167.8,1014,44.8,,0,,0,,Partially cloudy,partly-cloudy-night,"CZOL,CXEC,AU867"
```

I am pretty new to Python so I assume this is something simple, I did some searches but I think I am missing the proper terminology of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: A start could be: [csv to dataframe python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=csv+to+dataframe+python)

Comment: But depending on the level you are at currently, you might need [Getting Started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/), or [Python Developer’s Guide](https://devguide.python.org/), or anything in between